# various OxyPlot project types not supported in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: oxyplot

I want to fix an OxyPlot bug. Upon opening `OxyPlot.sln` with Visual Studio 2013 Express, the following problems appear. This [support link suggests I need Portable Library Tools 2](http://discussion.oxyplot.org/topic/485861-why-cant-i-build-the-core-library/) but that software is meant for Visual Studio 2010. Installing it did not make a difference for Visual Studio 2013 Express. How do I get past this problem?

The first of the projects that will not open is `OxyPlot.csproj` which sounds essential. The bug I want to fix is in heat maps and might be common to multiple platforms. My target is WPF and I note that `OxyPlot.Wpf.csproj` is listed as one of the projects where there was no problem opening in VS 2013.

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
     - OxyPlot, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.csproj"
     - ExampleLibrary, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\ExampleLibrary\ExampleLibrary.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.Silverlight, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.Silverlight\OxyPlot.Silverlight.csproj"
     - SparklineDemo, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\Silverlight\SparklineDemo\SparklineDemo.csproj"
     - ExampleBrowser, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\Silverlight\ExampleBrowser\ExampleBrowser.csproj"
     - ExampleBrowser.Web, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\Silverlight\ExampleBrowser.Web\ExampleBrowser.Web.csproj"
     - ExportDemo, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\Silverlight\ExportDemo\ExportDemo.csproj"
     - SilverlightDemo, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\Silverlight\SilverlightDemo\SilverlightDemo.csproj"
     - ExampleBrowser, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\XamarinAndroid\ExampleBrowser\ExampleBrowser.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.XamarinAndroid, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.XamarinAndroid\OxyPlot.XamarinAndroid.csproj"
     - Histogram, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\Silverlight\HistogramTest\Histogram.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.XamarinIOS, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.XamarinIOS\OxyPlot.XamarinIOS.csproj"
     - ExampleBrowser, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\XamarinIOS\ExampleBrowser\ExampleBrowser.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.WP8, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.WP8\OxyPlot.WP8.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.Pdf_SL5, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.Pdf\OxyPlot.Pdf_SL5.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.WindowsUniversal, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.WindowsUniversal\OxyPlot.WindowsUniversal.csproj"
     - ExampleBrowser.Shared, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\WindowsUniversal\ExampleBrowser\ExampleBrowser.Shared\ExampleBrowser.Shared.shproj"
     - ExampleBrowser.Windows, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\WindowsUniversal\ExampleBrowser\ExampleBrowser.Windows\ExampleBrowser.Windows.csproj"
     - ExampleBrowser.WindowsPhone, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\WindowsUniversal\ExampleBrowser\ExampleBrowser.WindowsPhone\ExampleBrowser.WindowsPhone.csproj"


No changes required
These projects can be opened in Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing them.
     - Examples.WPF, "Examples.WPF"
     - DemoApplications, "DemoApplications"
     - Examples.WindowsForms, "Examples.WindowsForms"
     - Examples.Silverlight, "Examples.Silverlight"
     - Examples.XamarinAndroid, "Examples.XamarinAndroid"
     - Examples.GtkSharp, "Examples.GtkSharp"
     - OxyPlot.Wpf, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.Wpf\OxyPlot.Wpf.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.Tests, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.Tests\OxyPlot.Tests.csproj"
     - SimpleDemo, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\WPF\SimpleDemo\SimpleDemo.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.Pdf, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.Pdf\OxyPlot.Pdf.csproj"
     - ExportDemo, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\WPF\ExportDemo\ExportDemo.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.Xps, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.Xps\OxyPlot.Xps.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.OpenXml, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.OpenXml\OxyPlot.OpenXml.csproj"
     - ExampleBrowser, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\WPF\ExampleBrowser\ExampleBrowser.csproj"
     - WorldStatisticsDemo, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\WPF\WorldStatisticsDemo\WorldStatisticsDemo.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.Wpf.Tests, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.Wpf.Tests\OxyPlot.Wpf.Tests.csproj"
     - MemoryTest, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\WPF\MemoryTest\MemoryTest.csproj"
     - WpfExamples, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\WPF\WpfExamples\WpfExamples.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.WindowsForms, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.WindowsForms\OxyPlot.WindowsForms.csproj"
     - ExampleBrowser, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\WindowsForms\ExampleBrowser\ExampleBrowser.csproj"
     - WindowsFormsDemo, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\WindowsForms\WindowsFormsDemo\WindowsFormsDemo.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.Pdf.Tests, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.Pdf.Tests\OxyPlot.Pdf.Tests.csproj"
     - OxyPlot.GtkSharp, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.GtkSharp\OxyPlot.GtkSharp.csproj"
     - GtkSharpDemo, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\GtkSharp\GtkSharpDemo\GtkSharpDemo.csproj"
     - ExampleBrowser, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\GtkSharp\ExampleBrowser\ExampleBrowser.csproj"
     - MathBlockDemo, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\WPF\MathBlockDemo\MathBlockDemo.csproj"
     - Examples.XamarinIOS, "Examples.XamarinIOS"
     - PerformanceTest, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\PerformanceTest\PerformanceTest.csproj"
     - PerformanceTests, "PerformanceTests"
     - Examples.WindowsUniversal, "Examples.WindowsUniversal"
     - OxyPlot, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot.sln"
```

Opening `OxyPlot.Wpf.sln` results in similar errors.

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
     - OxyPlot, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot\OxyPlot.csproj"
     - ExampleLibrary, "C:\Users\nacl\Documents\GitHub\oxyplot\Source\Examples\ExampleLibrary\ExampleLibrary.csproj"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please stop using Express edition and use Community Edition instead.

Community edition has identical features than Professional edition(see https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx).